# Post method returns 400 bad request Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript

So I'm having an issue with my create method in my angular. I'm using django for my backend, and I doublechecked, everything is working in the backend, with postman. Anyways here's the error. When I try to make a post request, this is the error that I get in the console. Below oyu may find the product that is sent from my end.

[image]

Comment: The API expects `product_category` to be an array, but you are sending it as a *string*.

Comment: I definetley get that, the idea behind product_category is that a product can have multiple, and thats why it's like that, but whenever I input just the name of the category, it doesn't want to take that in, and I'm not sure what workaround there is to that. I'll share the post method right away

Comment: What is the value of `this.productForm.value` before you store it into `formValues`?

Comment: there is no workaround. You need to send an array of strings. Even if there is only one category

Comment: @MihaiT, so would i need to enter it in the input box like this: [Sports]? How would i be sending that?   Nicholas, thats the first line that productForm.value is initialized, there's no other set value for it before

Comment: change your formValues to `const formValues= { ...this.productForm.value, product_category: [ this.productForm.value.product_category ] }`

Comment: "[sports]" is still a string :)  But, when you enter multiple ' categories ' , how do you send them ? you need to make an array with the input values. How is the user entering the values ? is it an input type text ? or which is the logic behind the categories input ?

Comment: Whether you selected one value or multiple you need to send that as an array with one element or "n" elements respectively. So before making the request convert that string into an array and send it.

Comment: Stavm, that is giving so many errors I cannot actually run the code. Mihal T, so the idea is that it'll be an input type text, and user has to type it on his own. So he creates a product, he enters the details, among those the category as well (it has to be something that exists in the database ofc). Nicholas, how would i convert the string into an array and then send it?

Comment: That's why I had asked you to paste the value of `this.productForm.value`, we can transform it before making the API call

Comment: As I said that's the first line where the value exists in the code. Any ideas on how we could change that?

Comment: And how do you check if the categories the user entered are in the DB ? and how do you know if the user entered 1 category or 10  in the input ?

Comment: I assumed that if the user enters an incorrect category, it would display an error message or something that doesn't allow the post to go through. About the second question, I don't really know Mihal. I'm quite to to Angular

Comment: What you should do is.
Get the categories on Frontend from the DB ( through backend ) . A list. ( an array of [{ value: 1, label: ' sports' }] . Where value is an unique identifier for that specific category. Add those categories as options to the `mat-select multiple` . Get the selected values ( you will get an array )  and send that on submit to your backend.

Comment: So you mean I should expeclity create a list with all the existing categories from the db, and then set them as options on the mat-select  multiple?

Comment: Yes. That way you are sure the users select from existing categories and you don't have to ' check ' for that anymore. Also, using a select ( with multiple possible values ) ensures that you know exactly which categories are selected. Because if not how can you know when the user enters : ' sports casual whatever ' that there are 3 categories and not 1 ? :) So yeah, that's the way to go

Comment: Gotcha, that seems pretty good, one more question though, I tried that before, made the code like on the select multiple material link thats also in the answer, but I couldn't get it to work still, any way that you could actually guide me with the code?

Comment: Do a `console.log(this.productForm.value)` in the first line of `onSubmit()` and paste that value here.

Comment: Nicholas, here it is, ``` {name: "ball", default_price: "100", description: "new", product_category: "Sports"}
default_price: "100"
description: "new"
name: "ball"
product_category: "Sports"
__proto__: Object                                                                                                            
``` Doesn't seem to wanna work lol, however it appears to be the same as the picture with the formValue that i have on the main post. So it's getting the values from what I'm typing in on the form

Comment: What if multiple categories are selected in that case what is the value - could you paste that here as well?

Comment: ```{name: "ball", default_price: "100", description: "new", product_category: "Sports, Classic"}
default_price: "100"
description: "new"
name: "ball"
product_category: "Sports, Classic"```    So same thing, it just that it's added with a coma, the other one.

Comment: @NicholasK he cannot ' select ' multiple values as he uses a text input. He should use a select dropdown. SikeYouth i cannot guide you 100% through the code. This is what you need to do by yourself using the Angular DOCS. But, what problems did you encounter while trying to use the Angular example for mat-select multiple ?

Comment: This should do the trick, add this after `formValues` is assigned:
`formValues["product_category"] = formValues.product_category.split(',').map(e => e.trim());`

Comment: @MihaiT: He needs to just send the string as an array irrespective of how many *categories* are there.

Comment: Nicholas you frigging leggend! IT WORKED. Could you explain what exactly happend so I have a clue please

Comment: @NicholasK are you 100% sure that the user will enter the categories divided by a `,` ? That is a ... very low quality way of doing this requirement.

Comment: @MihaiT: OP, can probably answer that better.

Comment: While I do understand that this is not the most ideal solution, its very prone to errors, I'm still gonna be using it as a solution, I just want to understand how it works exactly, and what happend there.

Comment: @SikeYouTh: So basically what happens is we fetch the `product_category` from `formValues` and split that *string* based on `,` which results in an array - to which we remove empty spaces and assign it back as the new value to `product_category`

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you so much Nicholas!

Comment: Sure, you can do that and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This may not be the ideal approach to the overall problem, but it does answer the immediate question at hand.*

As the error states you need to pass in an array (irrespective of how many categories are selected) rather than a string. Make the following change:

```
onSubmit() {
   const formValues = Object.assign({}, this.productForm.value);
   productForm["product_category"] = productForm["product_category"]
                                                .split(',').map(e => e.trim());
}
```

Here, the `product_category` from `formValues` is fetched and the *string* is split based on `,` which results in an array - to which empty spaces are removed and assigned back as the new value to `product_category`.

Comment: Nicholas, sorry to bother you again about this, but I have a question related to this. So what happens if we have a formgroup and a nested form group inside that. How would we then solve the same issue? Lets say we have  ```this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ something:[' '], somethingelse: this.formBuilder.group({ new: [' '], old:[' ']}) })```  How would we go about it then? Would I have to do what you did but for the name of the nested form group?

Comment: In that case `formValues` would have a nested object? You then would need to perform the same steps again but by fetching the *value* from this nested object.

Comment: So do you mean something like ```smthForm["somethingelse.new"]... In that sense fetch the data? Or am I misunderstanding you

Comment: More like: `form["abc"]["xyz"]`

Comment: So following it up with  the example from above it would be something like : ```form["somethingelse"]["new"] = form["somethingelse"]["new"].split(',').map(e=>e.trim()));``` Just trying to get strong confirmation on this lol

Comment: Yup. Looks fine to me, test it out to see if it works.

Comment: Just tested it out and it gave me this error: ```non_field_errors: ["Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."]``` Now that I think about it, it could be because on the model of this component, the nested one is set up as a list of dictionaries, but thats the idea, this could have a few dictionaries connected to it. So lets say that would be category which would have a list of products dictionaries with details in.

Comment: Your API expects only an array, you cannot pass in a dictionary.

Comment: Right, so how would I convert that to an array? Or it's not possible?